# Detect accelerometer motion in android

Tags: android

Im working on an application which needs to detect accelerometer motion like shake or tilt the phone to right, left, up and down, based on these motions i'm sending some keys to my UPnP device.

for example if right motion is detected increase the volume of the media server and viceversa.

Please help me on this.

I have tried some example. it is working fine for Left and right. but i need a better solution for up and down.

here i add the code.

```
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();


    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        float[] values = event.values;

        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        /*float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
                / (SensorManager.AXIS_X * SensorManager.AXIS_X);*/

        Log.d("Shakes","X: "+x+"  Y: "+y+"  Z: "+z);

        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((actualTime - lastUpdate) > 100) 
        {
            long diffTime = (actualTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = actualTime;


        if(Round(x,4)>8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");


        }
        else if(Round(x,4)<-8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");

        }
        else if(Round(z,4) < -0.0){
           Log.d("sensor", "=====UP====");


        }

        else if(Round(y,4) < 1.0){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====DOWN====");

        }

        float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

        if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
            //Log.d("sensor", "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
        last_z = z;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you able to solve your issue??

Answer (score 2):

The X axis is horizontal and points to the right, the Y axis is vertical and points up and the Z axis points towards the outside of the front face of the screen. In this system, coordinates behind the screen have negative Z values.

[image: All Motion]

for more detail [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

in your case try this.

```
        if(Round(x,4)>8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");


        }
        else if(Round(x,4)<-8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");

        }
        else if(Round(y,4) < 8.0){
           Log.d("sensor", "=====UP====");


        }

        else if(Round(y,4) < -8.0){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====DOWN====");

        }
```

Comment: hi CapDroid, Thanks for the suggestion,, i tried this ,but it will affect the user Thresholds. i mean to say the user should always  hold the phone in a vertical manner. if i use this values of y and if i hold the phone in a normal readable manner it will always send UP motion key.

Comment: im trying with some accurate values which will not affect the user normal way of redaing the phone. im trying with the combination of y and z. still not found any good results

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Round(x,4)>8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");


        }
        else if(Round(x,4)<-8.0000){
            Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");

        }
        else if (z >9 && z < 10)
            Log.d("sensor", "=====DOWN====");

        else if (z > -10 && z < -9)
             Log.d("sensor", "=====UP====");
```